# Unity check if two rotated objects overlaps

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to check if two objects(rect transforms) with rotation are overlapping? I tried to check it using recttransform.rect, but it only works if rotation is 0. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

```
if (myrecttransform.rectTransform.rect.Overlaps(line.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect)){
    //overlap
}
```

Comment: How did you use Overlap. Can you share the code?

Comment: i updated the post

Comment: Does it work accurately when rotation is 0?

Answer (score 2):

Add colliders and tags to them and check if collision occured and compare tags.

If it is a 2d project then you can just add to them `Rigidbody2D` and then just use this
`gameObject.renderer.bounds.Intersects(object2.renderer.bounds)`

Comment: But how to do it without colliders? I create one of my object from prefab, so I can't set collider to it in a proper way

Comment: You can easily assign anything you want to your prefab, both at compile and runtime(via scripts). If you want to do this without colliders you have to find mathematical formula for finding intersecting planes in 3d space. You can also assign colliders and use `Bounds.Intersects`

Comment: Thanks, but I am working with 2d UI objects, not 3d. Maybe there is a way to do it in 2d?

Comment: I attached Rigidbody2D component, but now I am having an error: "There is no renderer attached to object". This is very strange, because I have CanvasRenderer attached to my objects